# android how to install custom fonts on \system\fonts directory in rooted device

Tags: android, fonts, installation, system

I am going to develop an android app it works as font installer.
the target of my app is rooted device which does not include the desired font, and it goes to install from war\fonts\ to \system\fonts folder.
any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

First to test this code you must copy your custom fonts to `/sdcard/` I don't know if you are going to put them in `assets` or download them from internet. Anyways to test, use the following command lines:

`cd /<path_to_sdk>/platforms-tools/`

`./adb root`

`./adb remount`

`./adb push sample.ttf /sdcard/`

Now the code:

This code only execute a bunch of commands. Note that the important part is that this commands change the default android fonts by your own fonts. Make sure of always make a backup.

```
        Process process;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o remount /dev/mtdblock4 /system");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf  >> /sdcard/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /sdcard/sample.ttf >> /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o ro,remount /dev/mtdblock4 /system");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also, you must reboot your device after do this.

Comment: I would reccomend to use `mount -o rw,remount /system`, so without the `/dev/mtdblock4`, since that parameter is not required and differs from phone to phone. On my phone (Motorola Droid 4) it is `/dev/block/mmcblk1p20`. So leave out that parameter, it is not necessary but may cause trouble.